# Postgresql group month wise with missing values

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

first an example of my table:

```
id_object;time;value;status
1;2014-05-22 09:30:00;1234;1
1;2014-05-22 09:31:00;2341;2
1;2014-05-22 09:32:00;1234;1
...
1;2014-06-01 00:00:00;4321;1
...
```

Now i need count all rows with status=1 and id_object=1 monthwise for example. this is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
WHERE id_object=1
  AND status=1
  AND extract(YEAR FROM time)=2014
GROUP BY extract(MONTH FROM time)
```

The result for this example is:

```
2
1
```

2 for may and 1 for june but i need a output with all 12 months, also months with no data. for this example i need this ouput:

```
0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Thx for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) function like this:

```
select
    g.month,
    count(m)
from generate_series(1, 12) as g(month)
    left outer join my_table as m on
        m.id_object = 1 and
        m.status = 1 and
        extract(year from m.time) = 2014 and
        extract(month from m.time) = g.month
group by g.month
order by g.month
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1fe0b/7)</kbd>**

Comment: Except using something like `EXTRACT(...)` will cause the db to ignore indices (will be slow on large tables).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Except if the indexes were built using `extract()`

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse correct, but it was not the point of the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than comparing with an extracted value, you'll want to use a range-table instead.  Something that looks like this:

```
month  startOfMonth  nextMonth
1      '2014-01-01'  '2014-02-01'
2      '2014-02-01'  '2014-03-01'
......
12     '2014-12-01'  '2015-01-01'
```

As in @Roman's answer, we'll start with `generate_series()`, this time using it to generate the range table:

```
WITH Month_Range AS (SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM month) AS month, 
                            month AS startOfMonth,
                            month + INTERVAL '1 MONTH' AS nextMonth
                     FROM generate_series(CAST('2014-01-01' AS DATE),
                                          CAST('2014-12-01' AS DATE),
                                          INTERVAL '1 month') AS mr(month))
SELECT Month_Range.month, COUNT(My_Table) 
FROM Month_Range
LEFT JOIN My_Table
       ON My_Table.time >= Month_Range.startOfMonth
          AND My_Table.time < Month_Range.nextMonth
          AND my_table.id_object = 1
          AND my_table.status = 1
GROUP BY Month_Range.month
ORDER BY Month_Range.month
```

(As a side note, I'm now annoyed at how PostgreSQL handles intervals)

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1fe0b/47)</kbd>**

The use of the range will allow any index including `My_Table.time` to be used (although not if an index was built over an `EXTRACT`ed column.

## EDIT:

Modified query to take advantage of the fact that `generate_series(...)` will also handle date/time series.

Comment: That is not how interval's arithmetic is done in Postgresql. You just do `'2014-01-01'::date + (month - 1) * interval '1 month'`. No casting. No string building.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto - thanks for pointing that out.  I'm (still) used to DB2, which doesn't require dealing with any of the operands with strings.  Actually, your showing that `generate_series(...)` deals with date/time/timestamps is more useful (I probably need to read more of the reference for PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

`generate_series` can generate timestamp series

```
select
    g.month,
    count(t)
from
    generate_series(
        (select date_trunc('year', min(t.time)) from t),
        (select date_trunc('year', max(t.time)) + interval '11 months' from t),
        interval '1 month'
    ) as g(month)
    left outer join
    t on
        t.id_object = 1 and
        t.status = 1 and
        date_trunc('month', t.time) = g.month
where date_trunc('year', g.month) = '2014-01-01'::date
group by g.month
order by g.month
```

Comment: Except, given that it's likely the table doesn't have dates from the future, you won't have the full range of months.  Depending on the given `id_object` you don't know what time might be missing.  And unless you've generated an index including `DATE_TRUNC(...)` (less likely than one including the base column), this will _still_ ignore indices.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Ok I fixed the missing months part. About the _ignore indices_ part that is an interesting point but I don't have the time now to discuss it.