# Left join returning bad values

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2005, group-by, left-join

I'm not very good with SQL queries but I attempted to write this one:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YY,Orders.OrderDate) as Year,
DATEPART(MM,Orders.OrderDate) as Month,
(SUM(case when OrderDetails.ProductCode = 'XXX' then 
OrderDetails.ProductPrice else 0 end) + SUM(Orders.Total))
AS XXX 
FROM Orders 
LEFT JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID 
WHERE Orders.OrderStatus = 'Shipped' 
GROUP BY DATEPART(MM,Orders.OrderDate), DATEPART(YY,Orders.OrderDate) 
ORDER BY DATEPART(YY,Orders.OrderDate),DATEPART(MM,Orders.OrderDate)
```

The `OrderDetails` is linked to the `Orders` table by the field `OrderID`. In this `SELECT` query I'm trying to get the SUM of `OrderDetails.ProductPrice` when the `OrderDetails.ProductCode` is `XXX` and add it to the `Orders.Total` to get total amounts for each month/year.

The query is working except for one problem (that's probably either a amateur mistake or has been worked around several times). When performing the `LEFT JOIN`, the `OrderDetails` table can have multiple records linked to the `Orders` table which is throwing bad results in the `SUM(Orders.Total)`. I've isolated that issue I just can't seem to fix it.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Side note: using `DATEPART(...)` in the `GROUP BY`/`ORDER BY` will prevent the optimizer from using indices to fulfill that part of the query, potentially making it very slow.  If you can instead create a range table that you can join to (something like what I do [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156202/postgresql-group-month-wise-with-missing-values/24161958#24161958), although you'd need to use a recursive query to create the range), you should be able to do index-answerable comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that the `XXX` product only appears at most once for each order, then this should work:

```
SELECT year(o.OrderDate) as Year, month(o.OrderDate) as Month,
       (COALESCE(SUM(od.ProductPrice), 0) + SUM(o.Total)) AS XXX 
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN
     OrderDetails od
     ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID AND od.ProductCode = 'XXX'
WHERE o.OrderStatus = 'Shipped' 
GROUP BY year(o.OrderDate), month(o.OrderDate) 
ORDER BY year(o.OrderDate), month(o.OrderDate);
```

If it can appear multiple times, then move that part of the aggregation to a subquery:

```
SELECT year(o.OrderDate) as Year, month(o.OrderDate) as Month,
       (COALESCE(XXX, 0) + SUM(o.Total)) AS XXX 
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT od.OrderId, SUM(od.ProductPrice) as XXX
      FROM OrderDetails od
      WHERE od.ProductCode = 'XXX'
      GROUP BY od.OrderId
     ) od
     ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID 
WHERE o.OrderStatus = 'Shipped' 
GROUP BY year(o.OrderDate), month(o.OrderDate) 
ORDER BY year(o.OrderDate), month(o.OrderDate);
```